# Compilation error: “stdint.h: No such file or directory”

Tags: c, gcc

when trying to build kernel

I got this error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h:9:26: error: no include path in which to search for stdint.h
 # include_next <stdint.h>
```

when i looked in
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/

there is just one stdint.h and under include-fixed dir there are : limit.h and syslimit.h

Comment: do you use a cross compiler or the 'standard' gcc version for your OS ?

Comment: in my OS (ubuntu 18.04) gcc version 7.5.0, in the project it uses gcc 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end,

i resolved the problem by adding to `KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option,-ffreestanding)`

That restricts gcc use standard stdint `stdint-gcc.h`